# How to get location in android during background working in Android O without Google's Fused Location Provider?

Tags: android, geolocation

im searching information about how to get user's location with app being in background or even stopped; 
As I read, the background services are going to be stopped when app get's stopped: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html
so the most useful solution I found is useless now, some people suggest that now the best way to get it done is thru Google's Fused Location Provider, even the docs (Which I don't like because it's a property library, for a company that always gets data from everywhere, and now it's the only way to do it? Suspicious...), so that's why I am trying to find a way to do it thru normal android libraries and methods, do you know a way to do this that still works on android O(8)? It would be very sad and worrying that the system no longer provides ways to do basic functionality and now everything must rely on google api's with all the privacy problems...

Comment: I find it curious that you are complaining about "google api's with all the privacy problems". If you do not mind the user knowing about your continuous and frequent monitoring of their location, use a foreground service. Otherwise, live with only a few location updates per hour, which helps from both a power and a privacy standpoint.

Comment: Yeah but when the user accept me monitoring he wouldn't know about google monitoring too, why we have to deal explaining the user that we are sharing their location with google when it shouldn't be needed, and whit that we have to deal too with losing user trust because the data is not only going to our uses but with google behind, everybody can use it

Comment: "he wouldn't know about google monitoring too" -- if Google wants to monitor the user's location, Google does not need your app to do that.

Comment: Then why didn't he just put the functionality as a base on android libraries, instead of making developers go through the google library and terms. Besides, if you are not going to answer why you come to argue?